# Adding a svg is making my other div disappear. How to fix that?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a site and I have to add an email svg at the top header bar. But whenever I try to add it, it's making my carousal disappear. And also it is changing the margin of the div below. Is there any way to fix that?

It's the svg in the div class='email-button' causing the problem.

Thanks for answering everyone. I found that it's a problem in my vs code. I'm writing in a new editor now.

Here's my code:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(246, 253, 255);
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #257d61;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}

.clg-logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  height: inherit;
}

#header-bar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: navy;
}

.header-nav-bar {
  height: inherit;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators {
  height: 300px;
}

.U-signup {
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  align-self: center;
}

.signup-form-content {
  padding: 50px;
}

.signupheader {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 1S0px;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar li a {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.svg-1 {
  float: left;
}

.image-margin {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

 .email-button {
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--top bar-->
<div class="top-header">
  <div id="header-bar">
    <div>
      <svg style="color: white; margin-top:10px;margin-left:50px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone-fill svg-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.885.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.61.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z" fill="white"></path> </svg>
      <p style="color: white; display: flex;margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;" class="svg-1">9999999999</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email-button">
      <svg style="color: white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;opacity:0;}.cls-2{fill:#231f20;}</style></defs><title>email</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="email"><g id="email-2" data-name="email"><rect class="cls-1" width="24" height="24"></rect><path class="cls-2" d="M19,4H5A3,3,0,0,0,2,7V17a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H19a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V7A3,3,0,0,0,19,4Zm-.67,2L12,10.75,5.67,6ZM19,18H5a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V7.25l7.4,5.55a1,1,0,0,0,.6.2,1,1,0,0,0,.6-.2L20,7.25V17A1,1,0,0,1,19,18Z" fill="white"></path></g></g></g></svg>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row spacer-16 sids-60">
    <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto">
      <div class="float-left clg-logo">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images\logo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top image-margin" alt="">
            <b>CAMS</b>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 my-auto">
      <div class="float-right header-nav-bar">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Public Notices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<!--carousel slides-->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/12/bts-3-1-164008807816x9.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://media.gq.com/photos/62aa49bd3ade2278af3f4f25/16:9/w_2560%2Cc_limit/GettyImages-1389467249.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your css as well? and / or a link to the project? The chances are your svg is just the full width of the page and maintaining an aspect ratio, so you need to just make it smaller with CSS like: `.email-button svg{ with: 24px; }`

Comment: let me link my css coz I tried and it didn't work. The only thing disappearing is my carousal. The other div is only shifting a little.

Answer (score 0):

the class email-button doesn't have any size. Your svg inside has only a viewbox="0 0 24 24": no size meaning it will take the size of the defined element it is in.

Just add in your css:

```css
.email-button {
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
}
```

And tell me if it's ok, I tried, it works for me

Comment: I tried and it's still not working for me.

Comment: The carousal appears if I write its code twice I don't know why

Comment: your email-button is supposed to be in header-bar. It's coming after the div with 9999999, it goes next line. I think it's the general structure of your page which has to be checked, you have small elements breaking design. I will try to show you with grid how to do same lot simpler